# Select MAX and Calculate AVG

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select the MAX 5 (highest values) from C2, and then get the AVG value of C1 based on MAX 5 selection

```
+----+-------+
| C1 |   C2  |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   2.0 |
|  2 |   1.0 |
|  3 |   4.0 |
|  4 |   7.0 |
|  5 |   5.0 |
|  6 |   4.0 |
|  7 |   3.5 |
|  8 |   8.5 |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: can you provide more details, like how the result should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it in this way:

```
SELECT AVG(C1) 
FROM (
      SELECT c1, c2 
      FROM tbl 
      ORDER BY c2 DESC 
      LIMIT 5
      ) as tbl2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a subquery for max 5 c2 and  avg()

```
    select  avg(c1 )
    from my_table  m 
    inner join  (
        select  c2 
        from my_table  
        order by c2 desc 
        limit 5 
    ) t on m.c2 = t.c2
```